# Programmatically grouping and typehinting different classes

Tags: java, oop, generics, architecture, software-design

Given I have a class that uses some kind of searcher to get and display a list of URLs, like this:

```
package com.acme.displayer;

import com.acme.searcher.SearcherInterface;

class AcmeDisplayer {

    private SearcherInterface searcher;

    public AcmeDisplayer(SearcherInterface searcher) {
        this.searcher = searcher;
    }

    public void display() {
        List<String> urls = searcher.getUrls();

        for (String url : urls) {
            System.out.println(url);
        }
    }
}
```

Whereas the `SearcherInterface` looks like the following:

```
package com.acme.searcher;

public interface SearcherInterface {
    List<String> getUrls();
}
```

There's multiple implementations of these searchers. (One, for instance, only returns a hardcoded list of `String`s for testing purposes).

Another one, however, **performs HTTP Requests to whatever API and parses the response for URLs**, like so:

```
package com.acme.searcher.http;

import com.acme.searcher.SearcherInterface;

public class HttpSearcher implements SearcherInterface {
    private RequestPerformerInterface requestPerformer;
    private ParserInterface parser;

    public HttpSearcher(RequestPerformerInterface requestPerformer, ParserInterface parser) {
        this.requestPerformer = requestPerformer;
        this.parser = parser;
    }

    List<String> getUrls() {
        InputStream stream = requestPerformer.performRequest();

        return parser.parse(stream);
    }
}
```

The splitting of such an HTTP request is done because of seperation of concerns.

However, this is leading to a problem: A `Parser` might only be built for a certain API, which is represented by a certain `RequestPerformer`. So they need to be compatible. I've fiddled around with generic types for such a structure now, i.e. having a `TypeInterface` that both arguments of `HttpSearcher`s constructor should implement, but I didn't get it working... Another approach would be to just implement a check in one class if the other one is compatible with it, but that seems ugly.

Is there any way to achieve such a grouping of `RequestPerformer`s and `Parser`s by the API they're handling? Or is there something wrong with the architecture itself?

Comment: @JornVernee Haven't actually thought about using a factory here, thank you! I guess I was so deep into dependency injection and seperation of concerns in this problem, that I forgot about that, thanks for the hint in the right direction! Want to post as answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Done, I added some more words I couldn't phrase right before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `HttpSearcher` seems like such a device to group these 2 together. You could create a factory class that returns `HttpSearcher` and other classes like it, and code that factory to group the compatible `RequestPerformer`s and `Parser`s together.

The reason why I wouldn't advice leveraging the type system, e.g. through generics, is that the type `InputStream` can guarantee nothing about the format/type of data it holds. Separating the responsibility of getting the raw data, and parsing seems like a good idea, but you will still have to 'manually' group the compatible types together, because only you know what format/type of data the `InputStream` will hold.